# What should be the Interogative form of this sentence

Tags: questions

> She should have left him.

According to me, the interrogative form would be - "Shouldn't she have left him?"

What should be the interrogative form, suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can ask an open question: "Do you want to know the answer?"

Or I can hint at the answer I want you to give:
"Don't you want to know he answer?" Hint, hint.
"You do want to know the answer, don't you?"

So your answer, "Shouldn't she have left him?" is a **correct** answer; it is the way to ask the question if you want to prompt the answer, "Yes."

And the open question is "Should she have left him?"  This is just as good, but not a better answer.

Comment: I was coming to the same answer while searching through the net.

Answer (score 2):

To form an interrogative, simply reverse the order of the subject and the auxiliary verb:

*She should have left him*.  [declarative]

*Should she have left him*?  [interrogative]

Comment: While changing to interrgative, isn't sentence transformed to negative? Then why it isn't done in this case

Answer (score 1):

"Should she have left him?" would be the correct way of phrasing it.

Comment: if "Should she have left him" works then what will be the interrogative for "She shouldn't have left him." I personally think that while converting to interrogative, it becomes negative of assertive sentence. Please suggest what do you think?

Comment: @Sarthak123: Okay, i stand corrected. My apologies.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I was going with "Shouldn't she have left him"

Comment: @Sarthak123 No, there is no reason to convert to the negative when using an interrogative, any more than there is to convert to an interrogative when making a negative.